# Problema Hilos Sincronizados Java

Tags: java, hilos

Muy buenas a todos, estoy haciendo un ejercicio que consiste en una carrera de relevos en Java, pero se me atasca la parte de que salga un corredor cuando su antecesor termina, os muestro el código:

**Clase Corredor**

```
public class Corredor extends Thread{

*****SETERS AND GETERS*********************

public void run() {
    int numeroAle = generarNumeroAleatorio();

    synchronized (this) {

        if(ventana.isPistaEnUso()) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {

            ventana.reservarPista(this);

            while(!ventana.haLlegado(this) &&  !parar) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(numeroAle);
                }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    ventana.mover(corredor);
                });
            }

            System.out.println("ESTADO PISTA ANTES: "+ventana.isPistaEnUso());
            System.out.println("YA HE LLEGADO --> "+this.getName());
            ventana.desReservarPista(this);
            System.out.println("ESTADO PISTA DESPUES: "+ventana.isPistaEnUso());
            notifyAll();

        }
    }       
}
```

**Clase Ventana**

```
public Ventana(){
this.pistaEnUso = false;
}
private void iniciarHilos(){

    for(int i = 0; i < numeroHilos; i++)
    {
        hiloCorredores[i] = new Corredor(fichaCorredor[i] , this , Integer.valueOf(numVelocidad.getText()));
        hiloCorredores[i].setName(String.valueOf(i+1));
        hiloCorredores[i].start();

    }
}

public void reservarPista(Corredor corredor) {

    if(!pistaEnUso) {
        this.pistaEnUso = true;
    }

}

public void desReservarPista(Corredor corredor) {

    if(pistaEnUso) {
        this.pistaEnUso = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

}
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que el primer paso funciona: Sale el primer corredor y los demás se quedan quietos, pero cuando este llega al final (el primer corredor), se muestra el system.print de **ya he llegado corredor 1** pero no soy capaz de que se inicie el siguiente hilo una vez se muestre ese mensaje. Además, cuando el primer corredor llega y supuestamente sale el segundo, se produce el error **"IllegalMonitorStateException"** Se que viene debido al **.wait()** pero no se como solucionarlo.

PD He omitido código que considero que no es importante ya que por encima de esto hay una interfaz gráfica y no quería que hubiera código innecesario.

Espero haberme explicado correctamente, muchísimas gracias a todos!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que todo una pregunta: ¿Por qué necesitas usar hilos para resolver una problema de esta naturaleza? Puesto que el corredor 2 tiene que esperar a que el 1 termine, y el 3 a que termine el 1 y el 2 (y así sucesivamente), no veo la necesidad de hacer una implementación tan compleja (el simple hecho de usar hilos la hace compleja y propensa a errores).

No obstante a lo anterior hay varias cosas a corregir.

**1 - IllegalMonitorStateException**

Esta excepción es lanzada por el método `desReservarPista()` puesto que no está sincronizado y dentro de este estás llamando al método [Object#notifyAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()).

`notifyAll()` solo puede llamarse dentro de un método, o bloque, sincronizado ya que de lo contrario este lanza dicha excepción.

El [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()) es bastante claro en esto:

> IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of this object's monitor.

Traducción

> IllegalMonitorStateException - si el hilo actual no es el propietario del monitor de este objeto.

Y el modo de obtener el monitor de un objeto es a través de un método o bloque sincronizado.

**2 - Difinir recurso compartido**

Este punto es sumamente importante. En el código que compartes tienes un bloque sincronizado dentro de la clase que ejecutarás dentro de uno de los hilos. Aquí mismo llamas a los métodos `wait()` y `notifyAll()`. Esto es incorrecto puesto que donde se debe implementar el control de acceso concurrente es sobre el recurso que se va a compartir entre los diferentes hilos.

En tu caso el recurso compartido es la ventana, exactamente la variable `pistaEnUso`, ya que mientras esta esté en uso por un hilo el resto debe esperar. Por lo tanto debes sincronizar los métodos que utilizan esta variable y no el código del hilo.

**Solución**
Teniendo en cuenta todo lo dicho, el código debe ser algo como esto.

*Nota:* Es importante aclarar que quizá haya otras partes de tu código que requieran modificaciones.

**Clase Corredor**

```
public class Corredor extends Thread {

    *****SETERS AND GETERS*********************

    public void run() {
        try {
            int numeroAle = generarNumeroAleatorio();

            // Pone en espera al hilo si la pista está en uso
            // Cuando se desbloquea la pista toma el control sobre esta y el resto de hilos esperan
            ventana.reservarPista(this);

            while(!ventana.haLlegado(this) &&  !parar) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(numeroAle);
                }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    ventana.mover(corredor);
                });
            }

            // Le agrego el nombre de los hilos para saber quién es el que imprime
            System.out.println("ESTADO PISTA ANTES (" + getName() + "): " + ventana.isPistaEnUso());
            System.out.println("YA HE LLEGADO --> " + this.getName());

            // Libera la pista para que el resto de hilos que están esperando se desbloqueen
            ventana.desReservarPista(this);

            // Esto puede que no se ejecute en el orden correcto puesto que la línea anterior
            // desbloqueó la pista y otros hilos pueden ejecutarse
            // Por tales motivos la llamada a ventana.isPistaEnUso() puede devolver true
            System.out.println("ESTADO PISTA DESPUES (" + getName() + "): " + ventana.isPistaEnUso());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }
}
```

**Clase Ventana**

```
public class Ventana {

    // Resto del código de la clase

    public Ventana() {
        this.pistaEnUso = false;
    }

    private void iniciarHilos() {
        for(int i = 0; i < numeroHilos; i++) {
            hiloCorredores[i] = new Corredor(fichaCorredor[i] , this , Integer.valueOf(numVelocidad.getText()));
            hiloCorredores[i].setName(String.valueOf(i+1));
            hiloCorredores[i].start();
        }
    }

    // El parámetro corredor sobra
    // Sincronizado para garantizar que solo un hilo puede ejecutar este
    // método a la vez 
    public synchronized void reservarPista() throws InterruptedException {
        // Debe utilizarse un while porque cuando se libere puede que otro hilo
        // tome el monitor, por lo que sería incorrecto continuar. Por esto no
        // funciona con un if
        while (pistaEnUso) {
            wait();
        }

        this.pistaEnUso = true;
        // Notifico a todos los hilos que estén esperando, porque llamaron a wait(),
        // para que intenten obtener el monitor 
        notifyAll();
    }

    // El parámetro corredor sobra
    // Sincronizado para garantizar que solo un hilo puede ejecutar este
    // método a la vez
    public synchronized void desReservarPista() throws InterruptedException {
        while (!pistaEnUso) {
            wait();
        }

        this.pistaEnUso = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sii ya funciona!! Muchisimas gracias!! 

Se que es complicarse mucho la vida pero estamos haciendo en clase ejercicios con hilos y nos obligan a hacerlo así. El problema es que no había entendido correctamente el funcionamiento del synchronized pero ya me ha quedado más claro.

Muchísimas gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: Un gusto haberte ayudado. De todos modos te recomiendo que busques problemas que sean de hilos realmente, como el Productor-Consumidor. Saludos.